# Convexity of the set

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis, control-theory

$$
\dot x(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)\\
x(t_0)=x_0\\
x(t_f)=x_f\\
a\leq x\leq b
$$
$x(t)$ is driven by $u(t)$ to satisfy the above differential equation, two boundary conditions, and the inequality. Here, $x_0$ and $x_f\in[a,b]$, $t\in[t_0,t_f]$.

My question:

> What condition shall I impose on the above formulation to guarantee the feasible set of $u$, i.e. $\mathcal U(u)$ is convex in $u$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The boundary condition doesn't make sense, since $x$ is a vector. $[x_0, x_f]$ doesn't make sense also.

Comment: @obareey I only consider the scalar case. Sorry, there is a mistake, it should be $x_0$ and $x_f\in[a,b]$.

Comment: It is also convex in this case and you can also prove it like in the answer. Actually, you can prove it for the general case, i.e. $x \in C$ where $C$ is a convex set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any special conditions, it is already convex. To see that we can write the solution of the differential equation as

$$ x_f = x(t_f) = e^{A(t_f - t_0)} x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t_f} e^{A(t_f - \tau)} B u(\tau) d \tau $$

Now suppose $u_1$ and $u_2$ are two functions that satisfy the above equation, i.e. $u_1, u_2 \in \mathcal{U}(u)$. We need to show that $\alpha_1 u_1 + \alpha_2 u_2$ also satisfies it where $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 1$, $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 > 0$.

$$\begin{align}
\alpha_1 x_f &= \alpha_1 e^{A(t_f - t_0)} x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t_f} e^{A(t_f - \tau)} B [\alpha_1 u_1(\tau)] d \tau \\
\alpha_2 x_f &= \alpha_2 e^{A(t_f - t_0)} x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t_f} e^{A(t_f - \tau)} B [\alpha_2 u_2(\tau)] d \tau \\
x_f &= e^{A(t_f - t_0)} x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t_f} e^{A(t_f - \tau)} B [\alpha_1 u_1(\tau) + \alpha_2 u_2(\tau)] d \tau
\end{align}$$

This can easily be generalized to $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Yes, great. Thank you! Besides, how to prove the convexity of $\mathcal U(u)$ if there is an additional constraints $C(x)\geq 0$, where $C(x)$ is convex in $x$?

Comment: I didn't understand this. Is this another question? If so, can you provide more information?

Comment: Now I update my question (adding an additional constraints on $x$). Is $\mathcal U$ still convex? Thank you.